# How do I download text of Tweets using the API?

Tags: web-scraping, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to search Twitter for tweets containing certain keywords, and then download a dataset of all the tweets from the past two weeks that contain these keywords. The dataset should contain the text of the tweet, in addition to any links attached.

What is the procedure to do this with the Twitter API? I have a developer account.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we love to help others with their questions, we have an expectation that users first attempt to solve their problem themselves before coming to Stack Overflow for assistance. More information on the research expectations can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Try looking at the Twitter API documentation and testing something out, and if you're still stuck then, Stack Overflow might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

With Python you can use a library like [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). Here is a simple example to get you started.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

SEARCH_TERM = 'pizza'

api = TwitterAPI(<consumer key>, <consumer secret>, <access token key>, <access token secret>)

r = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': SEARCH_TERM})

for item in r:
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

This will return tweets from the last week. To get older tweets you must first request access to Twitter's Premium Search. Then, you can use the code example [here](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/premium_search.py) to get you started with Premium Search.